# STRTOTIME Date - Time Wont Change

Tags: php

im in the middle editting this js while it refering to this lines as data. i tried to edit the strtotime part but nothing is happening. tried to adding hours or minutes it still displays the same. how do i edit the result time ?

```
function dav_clock_time( $return_data = false ) {
$now          = strtotime( "now +4 hours 2 minutes" );
$next_tuesday = strtotime( "next Tuesday +4 hours 2 minutes" );

$time_dif = $next_tuesday - $now;

if ( $time_dif <= 0 ) {
    $next_tuesday = $next_tuesday + 604800;    // 1 week = 604800
}

$data_end_actions = date( 'Y/m/d', $next_tuesday );

if ( $return_data ) {
    return $data_end_actions;
}

echo $data_end_actions;
```

}

Comment: Editing `js`? And tag `php`?

Comment: What result do you get? What result are you getting?

Comment: editing js.which refers to this php as data.

Comment: @JohnConde im getting unix timestamp to be used with countdown

Comment: I meant for you to show an example of output that you are expecting and what you are actually getting. Put it in your question.